# Morphia query date range

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

What is the equivalent of the following Mongo query in Morphia?

```
db.events.find({ "date": { $gte: ISODate("2001-01-01") , $lt: ISODate("2001-01-02")} })
```

Currently I have the following code

```
Query<Event> query = dataStore.find(Event.class);
query.field("date").greaterThanOrEq(startDate).field("date").lessThan(endDate);
```

but it results in the following Mongo query

```
{ "$and" : [ { "date" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}}} , { "date" : { "$lt" : { "$date" : "2001-01-02T00:00:00.000Z"}}}]}
```

I suppose the end result is the same, but the resulting query is more verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `criteria` with `add` method

Something like

```java
Query<Event> query = datastore.find(Event.class);
query.criteria("date").greaterThanOrEq(startDate).add(query.criteria("date").lessThan(endDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a query then add date range condition like followed.

```
Query<Event> queryForEvent = ds.createQuery(Event.class);
queryForEvent.field("date").greaterThanOrEq(startDate);
queryForEvent.field("date").lessThan(endDate);
List<Event> eventList = queryForEvent.asList();
```

Hoping you will find it useful.